# How add an Action to a Button in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I created my Button to my cocos2d project using this code

```
CCMenuItem *starMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage 
  itemFromNormalImage:@"ButtonStar.jpg" selectedImage:@"ButtonStarSel.jpg" 
  target:self selector:@selector(starButtonTapped:)];
starMenuItem.position = ccp(60, 60);
CCMenu *starMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:starMenuItem, nil];
starMenu.position = CGPointZero;
[self addChild:starMenu];
```

Now i need to link my sprite jump action with this button..  How can i do this..?

Comment: Is your callback `startButtonTapped:` not getting called when you tap on the button?

Comment: http://ganbarugames.com/2011/01/menus-buttons-cocos2d/

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
CCLabelBMFont *startLabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Start Game" fntFile:@"Arial.fnt"];
CCMenuItemLabel *startItem = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:startLabel target:self selector:@selector(startGameTapped:)];
startItem.scale = 1; 

CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:startItem,nil];
[menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:20];
menu.position = ccp( winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
[self addChild:menu];
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you have to implement your button press handler method which you referred in your code as 
*selector:@selector(starButtonTapped:)*

```
- (void) starButtonTapped: (CCNode *) sender {
       CCLOG(@"you are here: starButtonTapped");
       // implement your action for button pressing, eg.:
        if (!blLetsJump) {
            blLetsJump = TRUE;
            CCSprite *s = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:100];
            CCSequence *seq = [CCSequence actions:
                              [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1.0 position:CGPointZero height:150 jumps:1],
                              [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:
                              ^{
                                    blLetsJump = FALSE;
                              }], nil];
            [s runAction:seq];
        }
}
```

for this jumping example you have to do this previously in your *init*:

```
-(id) init {
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
        CCSprite *jumpy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"yourjumpinghero.png"];
        jumpy.tag = 100;
        jumpy.position = ccp(160, 50);
        [self addChild:jumpy];

       // then add your button
    }
    return self;
}
```